# Handling partial return from recv() TCP in C

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

I've been reading through *[Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)* to get a handle on TCP connections. In one of the samples the client code for a simple TCP stream client looks like:

```
if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("recv");
    exit(1);
}

buf[numbytes] = '\0';

printf("Client: received '%s'\n", buf);

close(sockfd);
```

I've set the buffer to be smaller than the total number of bytes that I'm sending. I'm not quite sure how I can get the other bytes. Do I have to loop over `recv()` until I receive `'\0'`?

*Note on the server side I'm also implementing his `sendall()` function, so it should actually be sending everything to the client.

See also *[6.1. A Simple Stream Server](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html#simpleserver)* in the guide.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you will need multiple `recv()` calls, until you have all data.

To know when that is, using the return status from `recv()` is no good - it only tells you how many bytes you have received, not how many bytes are available, as some may still be in transit.

It is better if the data you receive somehow encodes the length of the total data. Read as many data until you know what the length is, then read until you have received `length` data. To do that, various approaches are possible; the common one is to make a buffer large enough to hold all data once you know what the length is.

Another approach is to use fixed-size buffers, and always try to receive `min(missing, bufsize)`, decreasing `missing` after each `recv()`.

Comment: Yet another approach is to use end byte with special value (like ETX) if you are sure this value cannot appear within the message, or start byte (STX) and end byte (ETX). It is more difficult to handle on receiver side, but more robust. If something went wrong and some data lost in transmission, data flow can be easily synchronised with STX/ETX, but in case of length prefix all hell breaks loose

Answer (score 14):

The first thing you need to learn when doing TCP/IP programming: 1 `write`/`send` call might take 
several `recv` calls to receive, and several write/send calls might need just 1 `recv` call to receive. And anything in-between.

You'll need to loop until you have all data. The return value of `recv()` tells you how much data you received. If you simply want to receive all data on the TCP connection, you can loop until `recv()` returns `0` - provided that the other end closes the TCP connection when it is done sending.

If you're sending records/lines/packets/commands or something similar, you need to make your own protocol over TCP, which might be as simple as "commands are delimited with `\n`".

The simple way to read/parse such a command would be to read 1 byte at a time, building up a buffer with the received bytes and check for a `\n` byte every time. Reading 1 byte is extremely inefficient, so you should read larger chunks at a time.

Since TCP is stream oriented and does not provide record/message boundaries it becomes a bit more tricky - you'd
have to `recv` a piece of bytes, check in the received buffer for a `\n` byte, if it's there - append the bytes to previously received bytes and output that message. Then check the remainder of the buffer after the `\n` - which might contain another whole message or just the start of another message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to loop over `recv()` until you receive `'\0'` or an 
error happen (negative value from `recv`) or `0` from `recv()`. 
For the first option: only if this zero is part of your 
protocol (the server sends it). However from your code it seems that 
the zero is just to be able to use the buffer content as a 
C-string (on the client side).

The check for a return value of `0` from `recv`: 
this means that the connection was closed (it could be part 
of your protocol that this happens.)

Comment: You can receive bytes with the value '\0'; the issue is when the count of the bytes returned is 0.

Comment: Why would he receive a `\0`? Unless he sent one? There is no evidence in the question about that.