# TCP memcpy buffer returns rubbish data using C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm doing something similar to Stack Overflow question *[Handling partial return from recv() TCP in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386142)*.

The data receive is bigger than the buffer initialised (for example, 1000 bytes). Therefore a temporary buffer of a bigger size (for example, 10000 bytes) is used. The problem is that the multiple data received is rubbish. I've already checked the offset to memcpy to the temporary buffer, but I keep receiving rubbish data.

This sample shows what I do:

First message received:

```
memcpy(tmpBuff, dataRecv, 1000);
offSet = offSet + 1000;
```

Second msg onwards:

```
memcpy(tmpBuffer + offSet, dataRecv, 1000);
```

Is there something I should check?

---

I've checked the TCP hex that was sent out. Apparently, the sender is sending an incomplete message. How my program works is that when the sender sends the message, it will pack (message header + actual message). the message header has some meta data, and one of it is the message length.

When the receiver receives the packet, it will get the message header using the message header offset and message header length. It will extract the message length, check if the current packet size is more than or equal to the message length and return the correct message size to the users. If there's a remaining amount of message left in the packet, it will store it into a temporary buffer and wait to receive the next packet. When it receives the next packet, it will check the message header for the message length and do the same thing.

If the sender pack three messages in a packet, each message have its own message header indicating the message length. Assume all three messages are 300 bytes each in length. Also assume that the second message sent is incomplete and turns out to be only 100 bytes.

When the receiver receives the three messages in a packet, it will return the first message correctly. Since the second message is incomplete, my program wouldn't know, and so it will return 100 bytes from the second message and 200 bytes from the third message since the message header indicates the total size is 300 bytes. Thus the second message returned will have some rubbish data.

As for the third message, my program will try to get the message length from the message header. Since the first 200 bytes are already returned, the message header is invalid. Thus, the message length returned to my program will be rubbish as well. Is there a way to check for a complete message?

Comment: Can you show your actual code ?

Comment: Yes, show the real code, not the tiny portion that you think is relevant, but all of it.

Comment: Do you get normal data in dataRecv and bad in tmpBuffer?

Comment: Yes, you should check how many bytes you actually receive.  Best guess without seeing code is that you think you are reading 1000 bytes but actually getting 5 real bytes of data and moving 995 of garbage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you are expecting 7000 bytes over the tcp connection. In this case it is very likely that your messages will be split into tcp packets with an actual payload size of let's say 1400 bytes (so 5 messages).

In this case it is perfectly possible consecutive `recv` calls with a target buffer of 1000 bytes will behave as follows:

```
recv -> reads 1000 bytes (packet 1)
recv -> reads 400 bytes (packet 1)
recv -> reads 1000 bytes (packet 2)
recv -> reads 400 bytes (packet 2)
...
```

Now, in this case, when reading the 400 bytes packet you still copy the full 1000 bytes to your larger buffer, actually pasting 600 bytes of rubbish in between. You should actually only memcpy the number of bytes received, which is the return value of `recv` itself. Of course you should also check if this value is 0 (socket closed) or less than zero (socket error).

Comment: +1. Most common socket programming mistake is to assume "recv" returned as many bytes as you passed in.  IP Fragmentation, TCP segmentation, tcp window size, and many other factors influence how many bytes are returned.  And is completely independent of how many bytes were "sent" with the corresponding send call().

Comment: Hi, Yup im aware of what KillianDS has mentioned. In fact, each 1400 msg will have a msg hdr which contain the msg length so that the receivng end will know the offset to memcpy and return to user. the funny thing is that if the sender sends 95 msg at a time, the receiver is able to receive all msg everytime. but if the sender sents 100 and above messages at a time, the rubbish data may appear. I actually sniff the network for the hex data and try to debug from there