# Socket programming issue with recv() receiving partial messages

Tags: c, linux

I have a socket that is receiving streaming stock tick data. However, I seem to get a lot of truncated messages, or what appears to be truncated messages. Here is how I am receiving data:

```
if((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("recv()");
    exit(1);
}
else {
    buf[numbytes] = '\0';
    // Process data
}
```

Can `recv()` receive just a partial message of what was sent?

My feeling is I might need another loop around the `recv()` call that receives until a complete message is sent. I know that a libcurl implementation I have (not possible to use libcurl here I would think) has an outer loop:

```
// Read the response (sum total bytes read in tot_bytes)
for(tot_bytes=0; ; tot_bytes += iolen)
{  
    wait_on_socket(sockfd, 1, 60000L);
    res = curl_easy_recv(curl, buf + tot_bytes, sizeof_buf - tot_bytes, &iolen);

    if(CURLE_OK != res) {
        // printf( "## %d", res );
        break;
    }
}
```

Do I need an `recv()` loop similar to the libcurl example (that verifiably works)?

Comment: Not entirely related, but why are you sending tick data over TCP? That stuff is normally multicast over UDP.

Comment: I am receiving, not sending.  they just emailed me a hostname and a port number, I didn't get any other technical instructions.  I just sent an email asking if I should use UDP.  but if I am using TCP and it works (aside from partial message issue I opened topic with) would it also work with UDP?  ie - they send UDP, I can recv() with UDP or TCP?  Also, they do send <soh><stx><etx> headers so I think I need to use those to detect a partial message and then when I recv() the next time thru, offset into the partial message in order to try and complete it ..  thx.

Comment: the UDP comment I don't get - you can lose data if you use UDP, right?

Comment: Yes, UDP can lose data. That's why it's used for ticks; if you miss a quote update, the exchange isn't going to wait and resend. The exchange just multicasts to everyone and hopefully you'll get most of it. I'm confused as to why your market-data system would be set-up differently. Usually the host and port refer to a multicast *group* that you have the *join*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, you need a loop.  `recv` only retrieves the data that's currently available; once any data has been read, it doesn't wait for more to appear before it returns.

The [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) says *"The receive calls normally return any data available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested."*

Answer (score 8):

We can also pass the flag to `recv` to wait until all the message has arrived. It works when you know the number of bytes to receive. You can pass the command like this.

```
numbytes =  recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, MSG_WAITALL);
```

Answer (score 3):

TCP does not respect message boundaries. That means that `recv()` is not guaranteed to get the entire message, exactly as you hypothesize. And that is indeed why you need a loop around your `recv()`. (That's also why upper-layer protocols like HTTP either close the socket, or prepend a length indicator, so the recipient knows exactly when to stop reading from the socket.)

Answer (score 1):

> can recv() receive just a partial message of what was sent?

Yes, indeed, if you use TCP. I think this can help you. 
[Handling partial return from recv() TCP in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386142/handling-partial-return-from-recv-tcp-in-c)

Comment: thx for link.  from reading that, actually the msgs I receive have headers.  eg <soh>2<symbol>,<sub-record><stx><base><exchange ID><delay time><price>, <element><modifier><day/session><etx>.  My recv typically returns 100's and last is truncated.  So, I should probably "process what I get" and set the next recv() to use an offset such that the last partial msg is completed.  don't think I can get these one by one, too much data.  this is RT feed for BATS.