# c socket send and receive an int instead of a char buffer

Tags: c, sockets

1: The server copy the file size into the buffer and send it:

```
  snprintf(t_buf, 255, "%" PRIu32, fsize);
  if(send(f_sockd, t_buf, sizeof(t_buf), 0) < 0){
    perror("error on sending file size\n");
    onexit(f_sockd, m_sockd, 0, 2);
  }
```

2: The client receives the file size and put it into fsize:

```
  if(recv(f_sockd, t_buf, sizeof(t_buf), 0) < 0){
    perror("error on receiving file size");
    onexit(f_sockd, 0 ,0 ,1);
  }
  fsize = atoi(t_buf);
```

----------------- The code above makes my program working perfectly!

The problem happens if i write this code instead of the previous one:
1: The server send fsize:

```
  if(send(f_sockd, &fsize, sizeof(fsize), 0) < 0){
    perror("error on sending file size\n");
    onexit(f_sockd, m_sockd, 0, 2);
  }
```

2: The client receives fsize:

```
  if(recv(f_sockd, &fsize, sizeof(fsize), 0) < 0){
    perror("error on receiving file size");
    onexit(f_sockd, 0, 0, 1);
  }
```

Where `uint32_t fsize;` and `char t_buf[256];`.
The problem is that with the first method all work but with the second method the client doesn't receive all file but only a piece of it. What is wrong with this code?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling Partial return from recv() TCP in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386142/handling-partial-return-from-recv-tcp-in-c)

Comment: Doesn't look like it, the above code is just wrong ;-).

Comment: Are the client and server on the same machine? What does _only a piece of it_ mean?

Comment: @hmjd yes!
Bart: can you explain me why please?:)

Comment: I misread. I thought fsize was a pointer to a buffer.

Comment: Are you saying that the value of fsize is different or that subsequent reads behave differently?

Comment: with the first method i receive the file, with the second nothing is received. Also the "printf fsize" is a strange number with the 2nd method!

Answer (score 1):

[recv(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) doesn't necessarily fill the complete output buffer - it might return fewer bytes depending on how much data is available:

> The receive calls normally return any data available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested.

The return value (when > 0) will be the number of bytes received, so you can call it in a loop if you want to be sure to receive everything.

Alternatively, you could pass the `MSG_WAITALL` flag:

> This flag requests that the operation block until the full request is satisfied. However, the call may still return less data than requested if a signal is caught, an error or disconnect occurs, or the next data to be received is of a different type than that returned.

So in your case, you could do something like:

```
ssize_t bytes = recv(f_sockd, &fsize, sizeof(fsize), MSG_WAITALL);

if(bytes == sizeof(fsize))
{
    /* received everything */
}
else
{
    /* something went wrong */
}
```

Comment: the server sent 20 bytes and the client receives 1801745249 O.o why?? :(

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without more data.

Could be [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). You should print out the value of `fsize`.

Could also be partial return from `recv()`, as was mentioned in a comment.

Comment: little endian, i'm running server and client on the same machine!