# recv - filling always the first bytes

Tags: c

`recv (sh , buff , 5000, 0 )`. 
Let assume, that my buff is mallocated for x bytes. How can I write the received bytes always from the beginning? I mean I wish to start with `*buff` and not with `buff+x`.

Comment: Can you please try to clarify that further? What do you mean by "write", here? `buff + x` would never make sense, that would be the first byte *after* your allocated space, and thus nothing you should touch in any way ...

Comment: If `buff` is allocated of the heap, and you haven't modified the pointer since allocate, it will point to the beginning of that allocated memory. So when you call `recv` with `buff` then `recv` will write the first received byte to the first byte pointed to by `buff`.

Comment: You do this as you show. The `recv` statement in your question tries to read 5000 bytes to where `buff` points to.

Comment: @unwind yes, I see now. Forget my question. I checked it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recv` starts always writing the received data to the address given (*buff).

To make your code robust you should read in a loop until all data has arrived (this implies that subsequent calls should write to `buff+received bytes`.

See also [Handling partial return from recv() TCP in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386142/handling-partial-return-from-recv-tcp-in-c)