# Why does POSIX not define a mid-layer socket API?

Tags: c, sockets, posix, standard-library

I am looking at socket programming again.  I get the details (well, I can copy them from various websites, and I know the code is enabling the Unix low-level procedures), but I don't get the POSIX logic and thinking in its API.

- **Why have they not defined a slightly higher-level interface built on these lower-level socket functions?**
  Presumably, such code could factor out code that is repeated often (and error-prone) into more convenient `FILE` like interfaces.  Factoring would seem even more appropriate than just convenient when the lower level use is the same in > 90% of its use. Almost all sockets use that I see in application programs open a socket, read and write to it and close the socket. Also, why does one need to bind, when this is really something that the open call always does?
- **What cases does the current interface even cover that could not easily be covered by an interface that would look almost like the FILE interface?**
  One explanation is that there are uses where one would not bind to a socket, for example, or where fgets/fputs/fprintf/fscanf like functionality would need something extra (time-outs)?

There must be a reason that I am missing. Otherwise, 20 years later, there would already be one or more standard libraries that facilitate this and that would be in wide use.  I couldn't find one on google that mimics all the `FILE` routines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C programming language is and will likely always be a lightweight one. You need to understand that C runs basically anywhere and some things need a long research and work to get standardized.
Also, I have seen that new libraries are added because C++ went ahead and made them standard so it's a kind of C sharing.

Please do note that you *can* "bind" a socket to a file through `fdopen(3)` and consider it as a binary file. Of course you will still need to bind it, make it listen, accept and all the actions you can do on a socket that won't work for a file.
Indeed, despite the similar interface, a socket acts only partially as a UNIX file: there's even an `errno` value, `ENOTSOCK` which indicates a socket specific operation on a non-socket file descriptor.

Furthermore, consider buffering. You do want a file write to be done in large chunks, thus a bigger buffering, to make it faster; this won't work for a socket as you need to send data immediately, that is, undelayed.
Consider this example:

```
char one = '1', two = '2', three = '3';
   fwrite(&one, 1, 1, socket_file);
   fprintf(socket_file, "%c\n", two);
   send(fd, &three, 1, 0);
```

where `fd` is a connected `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)` and `socket_file = fdopen(fd, "w+")`. The receiver will read 312 because there's no flush except upon process termination at the `FILE` layer, unlike with `send` where `three` is sent immediately.

Answer (score 3):

The point is strikingly simple:

Because sockets are *not* files.

Let me elaborate: `recv`/`send` works quite like `read`/`write`, if you limit yourself to linearly reading a file from the beginning, and to appending at its end.

However, you'll say, `send` doesn't let me write arbitrary lengths of data trough! If I try to send more data than fits into a protocol's packet buffer, it will throw an error!

And that's actually the beauty of sockets: you actually send the data away. you can't keep it; it's gone once it's sent, and it's not stored once it's received. Sockets give you a whole different set of abilities (like sending smaller packets than the maximum packet size of the network, for example), which on the other hand demand you take some control yourself.

EDIT: `send` will not "throw" an error. "throwing" is not a C/Posix way of handling errors. Instead it will return an error (from `man 2 send`):

> If the message is too long to pass atomically through the underlying protocol, the error EMSGSIZE is returned, and the message is not transmitted.

Comment: " If I try to send more data than fits into a protocol's packet buffer, it will throw an error!" It won't. It will tell you that it has not sent all the bytes, because they couldn't fit and you need to take care of that.

Comment: @black: does my clarification agree with you?

Comment: That's another possible cause of failure. But I meant when you try to send a buffer and it's partially sent and you need to call `send` again, starting from where it stopped.

Comment: That doesn't usually happen -- buffers are usually sent atomically, or not at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we're still on two different roads. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386142/handling-partial-return-from-recv-tcp-in-c?lq=1).

Comment: @black: that's the `recv` case, I was talking about `send`.

Comment: The same applies for `send`, `write` and so on. Typically you even need more `send`s than `recv`s. Note that this doesn't happen with UDP.

Comment: @black: ah ok, I see. I was assuming the sender already had taken that into account :) so I actually was one step behind you, mentally.