# How to determine if I received entire message from recv() calls

Tags: sockets, tcp, http-headers

I am practicing on socket programming, trying to send a http request and then receive some `SOCK_STREAM` data from a server. This question is about the receive process.

**Approach 1**: my current approach simply use a while loop

```
while((received = recv(sockfd, response, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0) {
        //process response
}

if(received < 0) {
        perror("Error receiving data!\n");
}
```

basically, make `recv()` calls until it finishes/closes (which returns 0 as ) or it hits an error.

However, I rarely see people doing this, most people on SO are suggesting of using length indicator, i.e., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862071/how-large-should-my-recv-buffer-be-when-calling-recv-in-the-socket-library) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386142/handling-partial-return-from-recv-tcp-in-c). Makes wonder if I missed anything with the above approach.

**Approach 2**: length indicator approach

Okay, regarding the most preferred length indicator approach, how to get the total length of the entire recv message?

Giving example as below

[image]

It's a HTTP header I retrieved, there's a field called `Content-Length`. Is it the length of the entire message (size of header + body = 468)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `recv()` in a loop until a disconnect/error is reported will only work correctly if the server closes the connection after sending the response (usually because the client did not request a keep-alive, or the server decided not to honor the keep-alive), and the server indicates in the response (or the protocol dictates) that socket closure is EOF for the message data.

In HTTP 0.9, there is no response line or response headers at all.  The requested file is sent as-is by itself, and EOF is indicated by socket closure.

In HTTP 1.0 and later, the `Content-Length` header (if present at all) is NOT the total size of the complete HTTP message, only of the message body.  The message header is variable-length, terminated by a `0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A` sequence of bytes.

The CORRECT way to read an HTTP response is to do the following:

If the request is using HTTP 0.9:

- read from the socket until the connection is closed/errors.
- then close the socket.

This is covered by the [original W3C specification of HTTP](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html).

Otherwise, if the response is using HTTP 1.0 or later:

- read from the socket until you encounter the `0x0D 0x0A` sequence of bytes denoting the end of the response line, which contains the HTTP version,  Status Code, and Reason text.
- then read from the socket until you encounter the `0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A` sequence of bytes denoting the end of the response headers.
- then analyze the response line and headers to know if a message body is present, and if so in what format it is being sent as, which dictates how you must read it.
- read the message body, if present:

  - if the response Status code is `1xx`, `204`, or `304`, or if the response is to a `HEAD` request, no message body is present.
- otherwise, if a `Transfer-Encoding` header is present and has a value other than `identity`, read the message body in [chunks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) until a 0-length chunk is read.
- otherwise, if a `Content-Length` header is present, read from the socket until the exact number of bytes specified have been read, no more, no less.
- otherwise, if the `Content-Type` header indicates a `multipart/...` media type, read from the socket and parse the MIME data until the final terminating MIME `boundary` is reached.
- otherwise, read from the socket until the connection is closed.
- if the response is not read in full successfully, or if a keep-alive is NOT being used (a `Connection: close` header is present in an HTTP 1.1 response, or a `Connection: keep-alive` header is not present in an HTTP 1.0 response), then close the socket.

This is covered by RFC 2616 ([Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) and [Section 8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8)), and by RFC 7230 ([Section 3.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) and [Section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6)).

Comment: "then read from the socket until you encounter the `0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A`" are you supposed to do this by reading one byte at a time or is there a way to use a buffer (eg: read N bytes into a buffer, with the risk reading past the response header).

Comment: @tigrou that is an implementation detail for you to decide for your own code. Use whatever approach you want.  You can certainly use a buffer (I do), just make sure you process it correctly.  You can certainly read in (a portion of) the message body into the buffer while you are still reading/processing the headers, simply don't process past the header bytes until you have finished analyzing the headers to know HOW to process the body bytes, as I described in my answer.