# Server socket does not receive the message the first time. Why does this happen?

Tags: c, sockets

I have hit a weird situation. I am creating a simple echo client-server. The client is able to send message to the server. The `accept` call succeeds in the server but for some reason, it does not detect the client message the first time. But when the client sends the message the second time, the server is able to detect the message and print it.

Here is the server snippet where I am accepting the client connection.

```
while(1) {
    // continuously listen for the new client-requests
    int client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&client,&client_socklen);
    if(client_fd > 0) {
     char b[10];
     while(1) {

      ssize_t response = recv(client_fd,b, 10, 0);
      if(response == 0) {printf("reached end of stream"); break;}
      if(response == -1) {printf("error"); break;}

     }

     fprintf("%s", b);

    }
}
```

When the client send the request the first time, the call to `accept` succeeds and the control enters the `if` block but there it does not receive message and just prints `reached end of stream`. But when the client again sends the message, it receives the message and prints it. Why does this happen? Client is sending a simple `echo!` message.

Client snippet:

```
    #include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SERVER_ADDR "localhost"
#define SERVER_PORT 8889


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int socket_fd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server_socket_addr;

    // Converts localhost into 0.0.0.0
    struct hostent *he = gethostbyname(SERVER_ADDR);
    unsigned long server_addr_nbo = *(unsigned long *)(he->h_addr_list[0]);

    // Create socket (IPv4, stream-based, protocol likely set to TCP)
    if (0 > (socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client failed to create socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero(&server_socket_addr, sizeof(server_socket_addr));
    server_socket_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_socket_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    server_socket_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = server_addr_nbo;

    // Connect socket to server
    if (0 > connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_socket_addr, sizeof(server_socket_addr))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client failed to connect to %s:%d!\n", SERVER_ADDR, SERVER_PORT);
        close(socket_fd);
        //          exit(1);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "client connected to to %s:%d!\n", SERVER_ADDR, SERVER_PORT);
        char *my_message = "hey!!"
        int bytes_sent = send(socket_fd, my_message, strlen(my_message), 0);
    }

    // Close the socket and return
    close(socket_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: accept should return after client connected, not send message.

Comment: What is your client *really* doing? Please try to show a [mcve] of the client.

Comment: May or may not related to your issue, but for security purposes, you need to properly null terminate the `b` buffer before printing it.  There's no guarantee that the client sent a null terminated message.  Further, TCP is a stream protocol not a message protocol. Even if the client sent a null terminated string, you might only receive partial data with the rest arriving on the next `recv` call.

Comment: Also, I just noticed.  how do you manage to invoke `fprintf` manage to work without passing a FILE to it?  Let's assume you really meant to use `printf`.  You don't actually print anything until after the client closes the connection.  In which case, you get whatever was left in the buffer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Added my client snippet

Comment: @selbie Added my client snippet

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you read 10 bytes at a time in a loop, until you get an error or the client closes the connection. ***But*** each time you read in the loop, you *overwrite* what you read previously. Try printing the string *inside* the loop (after making sure it's null-terminated of course).

Comment: I also suggest you print what `recv` returns when it's not zero or minus one. TCP connection are *streaming*, a single `recv` might not give you all that was sent in a single `send` call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It prints `b` when `response == 0`. What would be a good way to read messages? Could you show an example?

Comment: When `response == 0` it means the connection was closed, and the contents of the array `b` will be indeterminate (since nothing was actually read into it).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386142/1025391

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So you mean as soon as the client closes the connection the buffer will be become empty?

Comment: The buffer will only have contents if `recv` returns with a positive non-zero value.

Comment: The buffer always has contents of some kind. What's in the buffer will only have *meaning* if the immediately prior `recv()` returned a positive value. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Amanda, your client snippet is part of the question. If you delete it your question will be closed.

Comment: @user207421 I thought it was not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
if(client_fd > 0) {
     char b[10];
     while(1) {

      ssize_t response = recv(client_fd,b, 10, 0);
      if(response == 0) {printf("reached end of stream"); break;}
      if(response == -1) {printf("error"); break;}

     }

     fprintf("%s", b);
```

This:

```
if(client_fd > 0) {
     const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 10;
     char b[BUFFER_SIZE+1];  // +1 for null termination
     while(1) {
      b[0] = '\0';
      ssize_t response = recv(client_fd,b, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
      if(response == 0) {printf("reached end of stream"); break;}
      if(response == -1) {printf("error"); break;}
      b[response] = '\0';
      printf("%s\n", b);  //  \n so that the message will flush to the console
     }
```

Comment: Could you please explain the reason we do `b[0] = '\0';` and `b[response] = '\0';`?

Comment: For starters, **security**.  You say your server is an echo server.  If I my code connets to your server and sends you `"hey"` but without a terminating null char, your server will send me a lot more back than just the three characters I sent you, which could include a lot of sensitive data on your program's stack.   It also, makes debugging a lot easier - you can easily inspect the string in the IDE without a bunch of garbage characters.

Comment: I understood `b[response] = '\0';` where you null terminate a string. But in the statement `b[0] = '\0';` what does it mean to add `\0` just at the beginning of the string?

Comment: @Amanda It means nothing. You shouldn't be making any use of this buffer unless `recv()` returns positive. IMO you shouldn't be trying to null-terminate it either: you should be using the `recv()` return value as the length to print, copy, convert, etc.

Comment: @Amanda - `b[0] = '\0'` is equivalent to `strcpy(b, "")`.  It's a trivial initialization with trivial cost such that makes debugging easier.  And while it would be a bug to reference `b` if the `recv` call fails, you at least have it that buffer initialized to be an empty string so it is less likely to leak something it case it does.  I'm not in full agreement with user207421. At some point, if you got to print the data, you got to null terminate it.  But he is correct that you need to be diligent in referencing the length of the buffer for subsequent processing.

Comment: Not so. To print the data you use `printf("%.*s", count, buffer)`. No null-termination required. And no assuming you got the entire message.